# How to create swiping pages in iOS? Like using FragmentStatePagerAdapter in Android

Tags: android, ios, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller, pinterest

I've searched quite a lot and most people seem to be recommending either UICollectionView or UIPageViewController but both have drawbacks.

CollectionViews aren't a good implementation because each page will be really involved and will contain a vertical collectionview in it.

PageViewController I'm not sure about because most examples show initializing a view controller and putting it in an array, and Im not sure how I would implement the same type of view controller over and over again with different data and if it would be efficient for dynamic data in the range of 100s of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both a collection view and a page view controller set to side scroll mode would work well. Both manage large data models, where you only load the few that you need **right now** into memory.

The page view controller does not use an array of all of your child view controllers. Instead, you give it an array of the current view controller(s) and new view controllers that could be scrolled into view on the left or on the right (The specific details vary depending on how you set up your page view controller. You can set it up to show 2 pages at a time with a center spine like a book, but it doesn't sound like that's what you want.)

Comment: Hey I cant find a way by which I can repeat the same viewcontroller in pageviewcontroller as there is no way to find the index of the position I'm at or where I'm going to be. Everyone has different viewcontrollers and they use that to compare with their array to get the current index. Any solutions to that ?

Comment: It seems like the best options for you are using a page view controller or using a collection view set up to horizontal full-screen cells. Both approaches require some work to get right, and both are quite viable. So yes, there are "solutions to that" but it's beyond the scope of a SO question to explain what's involved. I suggest searching for tutorial.

Comment: There is a tutorial in the Xcode help system called "PhotoScroller" that uses a page view controller to implement scrolling between full-screen images, but it also supports tiling to allow viewing very large images. (Thus it includes complexity that you don't need.) Plus, it's written in Objective-C against iOS 6, so it's gotten kind of out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

A: Page view controller - feed with ViewControllers (better for views with some logic or functionality)

B: CollectionView - feed with prototype cells (better for many not full screen items, with not simple logic like a tap)

C: ScrollView - feed with a view (better for simple full screen views). Remember to enable the "Paging enable"